# Finding if any key value is true

Tags: javascript

Hi there I am trying to find out if any key value is true of an object.

The following works only for objects without having nested objects.

I am trying to check if any key in the objects no matter parent or child has got true value

```
const odb = {
  "all": true,
  "allA": false,
  "allB": false,
  "allC": {
    "allD": false,
    "allE": false,
  }
}


const isAnyKeyValueTrue = o => !Object.keys(o).find(k => !o[k]);

console.log(isAnyKeyValueTrue(odb));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the value is an object, and if it is, call `isAnyKeyValueTrue` again. Also, to be more semantically correct, I have used [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `find`. I use `&& o[k]` to make sure `null` is not given to the function (since `typeof null === "object"`).

```js
const odb = {
  "all": false,
  "allA": false,
  "allB": false,
  "allC": {
    "allD": false,
    "allE": { "allF": true },
  }
}


const isAnyKeyValueTrue = o => Object.keys(o).some(k => typeof o[k] === "object" && o[k] ? isAnyKeyValueTrue(o[k]) : o[k] === true);

console.log(isAnyKeyValueTrue(odb));
```

Comment: The only minor tweak is that you can drop the `=== true` assuming the values are boolean, which may be inferred from the example (although not known for sure). Your solution is more complete if the value type can be non-boolean, in which case this would explicitly check for `true` instead of matching on other truthy values. Upvoted either way though

Comment: @nate-kumar hello sir, can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334007/multiple-checkbox-state-management-react

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that if we do not find matched result in current level,then we need to use `||` to find in the children level by invoke the current function recursively

```js
const odb = {
  "all": false,
  "allA": false,
  "allB": false,
  "allC": {
    "allD": false,
    "allE": false,
    'allF':{
      'allG':true
    }
  }
}


const isAnyKeyValueTrue = o => Object.values(o).some(v => ((typeof v == `boolean`) && v) || isAnyKeyValueTrue(v)) 

console.log(isAnyKeyValueTrue(odb));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const odb = {
  "all": false,
  "allA": false,
  "allB": false,
  "allC": {
    "allD": false,
    "allE": { "allF": true },
  }
}

const isTrue = (obj) => {
    let result = false;
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] === true) {
        result = true;
        break;
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        result = isTrue(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
    console.log(isTrue(odb));
```